# Is it possible to configure 2 email hosts using EmailMessage?

Tags: django, email, settings

I want to send an email from  different email host depending on the status. Heres the pseudo-code
Currently using django send_mail and EmailMessage for the core.mail module

```
if status == "accepted":
    letter = Letter().accept
    # send from currentmail
    msg = EmailMessage('blah blah', letter, 'currentmail', [to@mail.com])
else:
    letter = Letter().decline
    # send from other mail host
     msg = EmailMessage('blah blah', letter, 'othermailhost', [to@mail.com])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```

and my settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'blah@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't available in core.

If you want to use different smtp server based on your own rules then you need to create the connections manually, and python lets you do this by using smtplib:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html

Comment: no other answers so I will take your word for it, and accept it as the answer

Comment: Remember to inspect the code always, it's really helpfull: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py#L201

Comment: oh awesome! the source code. did not even think about that